# Error When Copying a Vector into another vector

Tags: c++, vector

There are two vectors "ImgCoordinatesList" & "ImgCoordinatesListCopy".

The first vector continuously receives values which are pushbacked.(x,y,Type - I have previously defined a struct which has int,int,string and its object is list_obj)

Once the function "ImgCreation" is called, the contents of the first vector should be copied into the "ImgCoordinatesListCopy" vector and the contents inside this copy vector should be used for further processing.

But the method what i did produced errors.

```
void SliceImageNew::BuildImgCoordinatesList(const long X, const long Y, string Type)
{
    //Creates the Structure for one x,y,type coordinate
    list_obj.x = X;
    list_obj.y = Y;
    list_obj.Coordinates_Type = Type;

    //Pushes the structure into a vector which eventually forms a vector of structs
    ImgCoordinatesList.push_back(list_obj);
}

void SliceImageNew::ImgCreation()
{
    ImgCoordinatesListCopy.resize(ImgCoordinatesList.size());
    copy(ImgCoordinatesList.begin(), ImgCoordinatesList.end(), ImgCoordinatesListCopy.begin());
    //ImgCoordinatesListCopy = ImgCoordinatesList; //Copy the contents into another vector and create image with the copy vector

    ImgCoordinatesList.erase(ImgCoordinatesList.begin(), ImgCoordinatesList.end());//Clear the vector after copying the contents into another vector
    PlotImgCoordinates();
    //SaveSliceImg();
    //ClearImgCoordinatesList();

}

void SliceImageNew::PlotImgCoordinates()
{
    static int SliceImgCount = 1;
    Mat SliceImg(Size(1920, 1080), CV_16UC3); // Blank Image with White Background and 1920*1080 Dimensions
    for (int i = 1; i!=ImgCoordinatesListCopy.size(); i++)
    {
        //Color differentiation between Mark and Jump Lines
        if (ImgCoordinatesListCopy[i].Coordinates_Type == "Mark")
        {
            //cout << "This is a mark line" << endl;
            line(SliceImg, Point(ImgCoordinatesListCopy[i - 1].x, ImgCoordinatesListCopy[i - 1].y), Point(ImgCoordinatesListCopy[i].x, ImgCoordinatesListCopy[i].y), Scalar(255, 255, 155), 4, 2, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            //cout << "This is a jump line" << endl;
            line(SliceImg, Point(ImgCoordinatesListCopy[i - 1].x, ImgCoordinatesListCopy[i - 1].y), Point(ImgCoordinatesListCopy[i].x, ImgCoordinatesListCopy[i].y), Scalar(255, 100, 155), 4, 2, 0);
        }


    }
//Creating Legends for the Plot
    putText(SliceImg, "Mark Line", cvPoint(1600, 40),
        FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, (255, 0, 0), 2);
    line(SliceImg, Point(1540, 35), Point(1590, 35), Scalar(255, 255, 155), 4, 2, 0);

    putText(SliceImg, "Jump Line", cvPoint(1600, 80),
        FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, (255, 0, 0), 2);
    line(SliceImg, Point(1540, 75), Point(1590, 75), Scalar(255, 100, 155), 4, 2, 0);

    //Providing unique names for every picture that is being saved
    name << "Slice" << SliceImgCount << ".jpg";

    // Saving the image 
    imwrite(name.str(), SliceImg);
    SliceImgCount++; //Increment the count to provide unique names to the images
    waitKey(0);
}
```

I have attached an image which shows the code and the error generated [image]

While debugging, the highlighted line in the image produced that error!

Could someone help me?

Comment: Don't post code as images. Post code as text.

Comment: Vector size can be `0`.

Comment: change `!=` to `<`

Comment: For starters, follow the dialog's advice and "Press Retry to debug the application". Then inspect the offending index and the vector.

Comment: `The first vector continuously receives values which are pushbacked.` - if you have multiple threads then make sure your code is thread safe

Comment: @LogicStuff : I wanted to start indexing from 1 because, the output is an image which will draw lines from data present in  previous vector index to current vector index

Comment: More than likely not the problem but `ImgCoordinatesList.erase(ImgCoordinatesList.begin(), ImgCoordinatesList.end());` can be replaced with `ImgCoordinatesList.clear()`.

Comment: @Ramanan The error means what it says.  I don't know what else to tell you -- the subscript `i` is out of bounds.  Your code should be checking for `ImgCoordinatesList.empty()` anyway, regardless of whether you believe there are items in the vector.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution!

I had messed up with the object declaration of the "SliceImageNew" class. After correction it works fine and draws the image perfectly.